# Unable to add foreign key to my table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to add a foreign key to my user table. 
All of my tables are InnoDB, and are using the same charset. I've got not idea as to why it isn't working :(.

Here is a screenshot of the user table:
[image]

As you can see, my userid, is an integer with the max length of 10.

This is the second table (called Content Enabled):
[image]

userid, in Content enabler, is identical to the userid in the users table, except it's not a primary index.

```
When I want to link them via a foreign key, using this query:
ALTER TABLE  `contentenabler` ADD FOREIGN KEY (  `userid` ) REFERENCES  `tietgen`.`users` (
`userid`
) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
```

This returns the error **Error creating foreign key on userid (check data types)**

As far as I can see, the data type are the same, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`userid` is `UNSIGNED` in your `users` table, but not your other table.

Comment: Thank you, one of those errors that seem so obvious when you point it out! >_< Well, you saved me a lot of time ^^, I'll accept the answer as soon as I can

Comment: Remember, most of us can only answer these questions because we did the same thing at some point. :-p